# Can't get single value from this php array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

```
var_dump($locations);
```

displays :

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(WP_Term)#3193 (10) { 
        ["term_id"]=> int(11) 
        ["name"]=> string(15) "Agence Himalaya" 
        ["slug"]=> string(15) "agence-himalaya" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(11) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(8) "location" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(0) 
        ["count"]=> int(1) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
    } 
}
```

I need to get the `["name"]` value in this array

I tried `$locations[0]["name"]` and different things, but I don't manage to get the items value.

Hugo

Comment: `$locations[0]->name`?

Comment: Thanks, it does the trick, i get   string(15) "Agence Himalaya". Is there a way to get only the string ?

Comment: @Hugo M., Please put your array like in print_r($locations) in your question...

Comment: Because you use vardump.It will also print the type of result.Just use `echo` to print the string only

Comment: @amow You're right, as a beginner i didn't know that :)

Comment: @Angel my problem is solved, but I'll do that next time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WP_Term` is an object, and if this doesn't implement `ArrayAccess`, you cant use `$obj['name']` to read it's name property.

In case of `WP_Term`, `$name` is an public var, so you could just use `$obj->name`.

In your case, the solution is

```
$name = $locations[0]->name;
```